# How do I reopen an issue in Jira that I created and closed myself?

Tags: git, github, jira

I accidentally closed an issue in Jira whilst still having the issue checked out in sourcetree. To push that commit I need an open issue with the same name in Jira but I closed it and cannot open it.

I have tried cloning the issue and renaming the branch in source tree to the new issue but that did not work but it is possible I did it wrong. Still new to using Git/Jira.

This is the error I receive. 
`JIRA Issue does not match JQL Query: status="in progress" and assignee is not EMPTY and project="PROJECTNAME" and component="PROJECT_COMPONENT`"`

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to have a Jira admin re-open the issue for you.